# AEM workflow email notification from email address

Tags: aem

I need to override the default email address set in " Day CQ Mail Service" because I need it to show different email address for workflow notification.

Based from the documentation [1] "When you receive workflow email notifications, both the from-email address and the host URL prefix are set to default values. You can change these values by configuring the Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service in the Web Console. If you do so, it is recommended to persist the change in the repository."

[1] https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/notification.html#Configuring the Workflow Email Notification Service

I was able to set the from-email-address in "Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service" and verified as well the values are saved in jcr repository "/apps/system/config/com.day.cq.workflow.impl.email.EMailNotificationService.config". Even after doing so, the from-email-address that appears in the workflow email notification is still the same value set in "Day CQ Mail Service".

Any other option for me to try?

Answer (score 1):

After making changes to the `Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service` via the web console, have you tried bouncing the `Day Communique 5 Workflow Implementation` bundle? I believe the properties from the `Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service` are read during the activate method when the `Day Communique 5 Workflow Implementation` bundle starts up.

It makes sense that the properties are being persisted in the JCR after modifying the values for the `Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service`, but bouncing the `Day Communique 5 Workflow Implementation` should re-read the values.

Comment: I have done the stop/start of "Day Communique 5 Workflow Implementation" but it did not fix the issue.